# Avoiding scientific salami slicing

Tags: publications, research-dissemination, bioinformatics

As part of my master thesis in bioinformatics I built a tool [A](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/BioCor/), which is similar to tool [B](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/GOSemSim/) which uses other data. Tool's B [original paper](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/26/7/976/213143/GOSemSim-an-R-package-for-measuring-semantic) is a description of the software and methods implemented, because the methods where already described and tested in other articles.

The method on which A relays hasn't been used before in this area. I was considering describing the tool first in a manuscript and then describing how it solves a problem in the area of interest of the group in another article. Dividing the article of the tool in two I expect to get the attention of the people using and developing tools and methods and make aware of such a tool to people who might want to use it.

The applications of tool A may be as broad (or even broader) as the applications of tool B, which has 6 different applications (as listed in its web page), and I don't have the resources to test in all the applications

Would be this considered [scientific salami slicing](http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v4/n1/full/nmat1305.html)?

<sub>Rereading my question perhaps I am overestimating the usefulness of the tool.</sub>

Comment: This is an important question, but I think its answer depends on field-specific knowledge and customs.  I'm not sure there is a generally useful answer that would apply broadly.

Comment: I included the "field" specific tag to focus and avoid the too-broad closure. But I welcome answers from other fields :D

Comment: @Enthusiastic is the question now more specific?

Comment: For the record, I don't think the question is too broad.  I think that its answer depends too much on the specifics of the research project in question.  It also has a title that does not match the content of the question.

Comment: This does depend somewhat on the specifics as mentioned by others, but to me (as someone knowledgeable about this field) it does not sound like a clear case of salami slicing. For example, the journal *Nucleic Acids Research* has a special webserver issue, in which short papers describing bioinformatic tools are published. The journal *Bioinformatics* has an *Application Note* format which is somewhat similar. Both journals are notable in this subfield. These publications can be separate from a paper describing the application of the tool to answer a biological question.

Comment: I see little value of publishing a method/algorithm without reference to the problem that is solved, so I recommend publishing a single peer-reviewed paper of the method and underlying algorithm of your tool, along with the problem that can be solved with the method. I also recommend that you write a user manual/tutorial for your tool, since this will significantly increase your tool's user base. This manual needn't be peer-reviewed, but it should evolve as the tool evolves, that is, you should update it with every (significant) new release of your tool.

Comment: The tool/method can be applied to different problems, although it was thought for one of them. It already have documentation and a manual. Thanks for the advice